# Unable to run Aptana Studio 3 on Big Sur

Tags: aptana

I installed Aptana Studio 3 (v3.7.2.201807301111) on Mac Big Sur with 16GB ram but I can't get it to run. It appears momentarily in the dock then disappears with no errors.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

have a look to the log file, this is:
<your_workspace_dir>.metadata/.log

you can open the file from terminal with:

```
open -a /Applications/TextEdit.app $HOME/Documents/Aptana_Studio_Workspace/.metadata/.log
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but all searches result in file does not exist. I tried downloading the app again but the same thing happened.